# Could this queue implementation enable lower latency messaging, when compared to the LMAX disruptor?

Tags: java, concurrency, message-queue, nonblocking, disruptor-pattern

I've developed a queue which allows a single consumer and producer to offer/poll elements from the queue concurrently without synchronization or CAS operations on every offer/poll. Instead there only needs to be one atomic operation when the tail section of the queue is empty.
This queue aims to reduce latency in cases where the queue is buffered and the consumer does not catch up with the producer.

In the question I'd like review implementation (the code has not been reviewed by anyone else yet so would be great to get a second opinion) and to discuss a pattern of use that I believe should significantly reduce latency, and whether this architecture could possibly run faster than the LMAX disruptor.

The code is on github at: 
https://github.com/aranhakki/experimental-performance/blob/master/java/src/concurrency/messaging/ConcurrentPollOfferArrayQueue.java

```
/*
 * Copyright 2014 Aran Hakki
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 * http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */

package concurrency.messaging;

// A non-blocking queue which allows concurrent offer and poll operations with minimal contention.
// Contention in offer and poll operations only occurs when offerArray, which acts as an incomming message buffer,
// becomes full, and we must wait for it too be swapped with the pollArray, acting as a outgoing message buffer,
// the most simple analogy would be too imaging two buckets, one we fill and at the same time we empty another bucket
// which already contains some liquid, then at the point the initial bucket becomes full, we swap it with the bucket that
// is being emptied. 

// It's possible that this mechanism might be faster than the LMAX disruptor, need to create tests to confirm.

public final class ConcurrentPollOfferArrayQueue<T> {

    private T[] offerArray;
    private T[] pollArray;

    public ConcurrentPollOfferArrayQueue(T[] _pollArray){
        offerArray = (T[]) new Object[_pollArray.length];
        pollArray = _pollArray;
    }

    private int offerIndex = 0;
    private int pollIndex = 0;

    public void offer(T t){
        if (offerIndex<offerArray.length){
            offerArray[offerIndex] = t;
            offerIndex++;
        } else {
            while(!arrayFlipped){

            }
            arrayFlipped = false;
            offerIndex = 0;
            offer(t);
        }
    }

    private volatile boolean arrayFlipped = false;

    public T poll(){
        if (pollIndex<pollArray.length){
            T t = pollArray[pollIndex];
            pollArray[pollIndex] = null;
            pollIndex++;
            return t;
        } else {
            pollIndex = 0;
            T[] pollArrayTmp = pollArray;
            pollArray = offerArray;
            offerArray = pollArrayTmp;
            arrayFlipped = true;
            return poll();
        }

    }

}
```

By using many of these queues in place of multiple producers and consumers all referencing the same queue, I image the latency could be reduced significantly.

Consider producers A, B, C all referencing single queue Q, and consumers E, E and F all referencing the same queue. This results in the following set of relationships and hence a lot of contention:

A writesTo Q

B writesTo Q

C writesTo Q

E writesTo Q

D writesTo Q

F writesTo Q

Using the queue I have developed one could have a queue between each producer and a single consumer aggregation thread, this thread would take elements of the tail of each producer queue and place them on the head of consumer queues. This would reduce contention significantly as we only ever have a single writer to a section of memory. The relation ships would now look as follows:

A writesTo headOf(AQ)

B writesTo headOf(BQ)

C writesTo headOf(CQ)

ConsumerAggregationThread writesTo tailOf(AQ)

ConsumerAggregationThread writesTo tailOf(BQ)

ConsumerAggregationThread writesTo tailOf(CQ)

ConsumerAggregationThread writesTo headOf(EQ)

ConsumerAggregationThread writesTo headOf(FQ)

ConsumerAggregationThread writesTo headOf(GQ)

E writesTo tailOf(EQ)

F writesTo tailOf(FQ)

G writesTo tailOf(GQ)

The relationships above ensures the single writer principle.

I'm keen to hear your thoughts.

Comment: You appear to be implementing something like the Exchanger.  It might offer higher throughput but not lower latency I suspect.  You could test it to see what difference it make.

Comment: You say that it allows concurrent offers, but it does not, as manipulation of the offer array's content and the offerIndex is not synchronized (nor are the indexes `volatile`). Plus the "busy wait" `while(!condition) {}` looks particularly wastefull. May be it works in your case, but I suspect it does not as advertised by your javadoc.

Comment: @GPI when I say concurrent offer/poll i mean it allows one thread to offer whilst another thread concurrently polls, I do not mean multple threads can offer or poll concurrently.

Comment: @Peter Lawrey, the producer does not have to wait for the consumer to poll an element before offering one, and so it is not a synchronous queue. This queue allows a single producer and consumer to offer/poll any number of elements concurrently without locking/atomic operations, apart from a single case, when the poll section of the queue is empty, at this point the offer section of the queue is swapped with the poll section atomically allowing the producer to offer to the empty section and the consumer to poll the non-empty section, this repeats every time the poll section becomes empty.

Comment: This queue will not likely provide lower latency than the disruptor as it exchanges batches of messages. The consumer has to wait on the producer filling the array before flipping.

Comment: If you want a lower latency queue than the disruptor then the following is a good option https://github.com/JCTools/JCTools/blob/master/jctools-core/src/main/java/org/jctools/queues/SpscArrayQueue.java. You should try tests similar to what can be found in this project.

Answer (score 0):

What do you guys think of this implementation? I have changed it round so that the polling thread triggers the queue switch, once the pollQueue is empty.

```
/*
* Copyright 2014 Aran Hakki
*
* Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
* you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
* You may obtain a copy of the License at
*
* http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
*
* Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
* distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
* WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
* See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
* limitations under the License.
*/



/* 
* A non-blocking queue which allows concurrent offer and poll operations with    minimal contention.
* Contention in offer and poll operations only occurs when pollQueue is empty and must be swapped with offer queue.
* This implementation does not make use of any low level Java memory optimizations e.g. using the Unsafe class or direct byte buffers,
* so its possible it could run much faster.
* If re-engineered to use lower level features its possible that this approach might be faster than the LMAX disruptor.
* I'm current observing an average latency of approx 6000ns.
*/

package concurrency.messaging;

import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Queue;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

public class ConcurrentPollOfferQueue<T> {

private class ThreadSafeSizeQueue<T> {
    private Queue<T> queue = new LinkedList<T>();
    private volatile AtomicInteger size = new AtomicInteger(0);

    public int size(){
        return size.get();
    }

    public void offer(T value){
        queue.offer(value);
        size.incrementAndGet();
    }

    public T poll(){
        T value = queue.poll();
        if (value!=null){
            size.decrementAndGet();
        }
        return value;
    }
}

private volatile ThreadSafeSizeQueue<T> offerQueue;
private volatile ThreadSafeSizeQueue<T> pollQueue;

private int capacity;

public ConcurrentPollOfferQueue(int capacity){
    this.capacity = capacity;
    offerQueue = new ThreadSafeSizeQueue<T>();
    pollQueue = new ThreadSafeSizeQueue<T>();
}

public void offer(T value){
    while(offerQueue.size()==capacity){/* wait for consumer to finishing consuming pollQueue */}
    offerQueue.offer(value);
}

public T poll(){
    T polled;
    while((polled = pollQueue.poll())==null){
        if (pollQueue.size()==0){
            ThreadSafeSizeQueue<T> tmpQueue = offerQueue;
            offerQueue = pollQueue;
            pollQueue = tmpQueue;
        } 
    }
    return polled;
}

public boolean isEmpty(){
    return pollQueue.size()==0;
}
```